# SQL Job executing Multiple Times

Tags: sql, sql-server, job-scheduling, sql-server-2016

I have a job on SQL job scheduler which is scheduled to run once a day.It executes and sends mails to users.But today i had abrupt behaviour in the same and 
I am getting the mails multiple times.

I had tried executing from query manually and it runs fine sending a single mail.
Also i had checked the history and the history shows single execution detail
What could be the reason for the same???

Answer (score 0):

you have execute job scheduler throw Right Click so it's exe multi times

Comment: Restart services will send mail stops.

Comment: @singh-No,its running on job scheduler and i haven't done it manually.

Comment: ok please remove unsentitems from logs:    SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log;
-- To get number of unsent emails 
select count(*) from msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems;
-- remove all the unsent emails
delete from msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems;